# Using na.locf to carry last value forward ignoring first rows when first observation is na

Tags: r, dplyr, zoo

I would like to make use of the [`na.locf`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/zoo/versions/1.8-0/topics/na.locf) to carry forward non-missing values for data frames where *first observation may be zero*.

## Problem

```
dta <- data.frame(A = c(NA, NA, 1, 2, 4, 5, NA, NA, NA),
                  B = c(NA, 5, 4, 5, 8, 9, NA, NA, 100))
dta %>% mutate_all(.funs = funs(na.locf(.)))
```

> Error in `mutate_impl(.data, dots)` :    Column `A` must be length 9
>   (the number of rows) or one, not 7

## Desired results

```
Vectorize(require)(package = c("dplyr", "zoo"),
                   character.only = TRUE)

dta <- data.frame(A = c(0, NA, 1, 2, 4, 5, NA, NA, NA),
                  B = c(0, 5, 4, 5, 8, 9, NA, NA, 100))
dta %>% mutate_all(.funs = funs(na.locf(.)))
```

## Workaround

The potential workaround would could involve replacing first set of `NAs` with zeros and carrying zero forward that could be later replaced but I'm interested in leaving NAs where they are and exploring if there is a convenient way to make `na.locf` ignore situations where the function did not receive non-NA value to start replacing.

Comment: @docendodiscimus You are right, this will work. I was doing `na.rm = TRUE`. My bad, too many hours spent doing one thing. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `na.rm = FALSE` argument noting that it can take an entire data frame -- you don't have to separately apply it to each column.

```
na.locf(dta, na.rm = FALSE)
```

This gives:

```
   A   B
1 NA  NA
2 NA   5
3  1   4
4  2   5
5  4   8
6  5   9
7  5   9
8  5   9
9  5 100
```

Also there `is na.locf0`:

```
dta %>% mutate_all(.funs = funs(na.locf0(.)))
```

See the help page `?na.locf` which documents the `na.rm` argument and also documents `na.locf0` .  Note that na.locf0 currently does have to be applied individually by column but always produces output of the same length.

Answer (score 3):

(Was in the process of writing this answer when @docendodiscimus's comment appeared)

From `?na.locf`:

> na.rm 
>   logical. Should leading NAs be removed?

So use `na.rm=FALSE`, optionally replacing the remaining `NA` values (i.e. those that were leading) with zeros thereafter:

```
dta <- data.frame(A = c(NA, NA, 1, 2, 4, 5, NA, NA, NA),
                  B = c(NA, 5, 4, 5, 8, 9, NA, NA, 100))
na_zero <- function(x) replace(x,is.na(x),0)
dta %>% mutate_all(.funs = funs(na.locf(.,na.rm=FALSE))) %>%
   mutate_all(.funs=funs(na_zero(.)))
```

Comment: except for the zero-replacement bit, which might be useful to others but which I think the OP doesn't actually need, @G.Grothendieck's answer is better than mine. Please go vote for his.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe as an additional hint, if you are using the **locf** function of the package **imputeTS** you can choose between several options on what to do with the trailing **NAs** via the parameter **na.remaining** :

Selections for na.remaining:

- keep" -  return the series with NAs
- "rm" -  remove remaining NAs
- "mean" -  replace remaining NAs by overall mean
- "rev" -  perform nocb / locf from the reverse direction

The desired output could thus be reached the following way:

```
dta <- data.frame(A = c(NA, NA, 1, 2, 4, 5, NA, NA, NA),
              B = c(NA, 5, 4, 5, 8, 9, NA, NA, 100))

library(imputeTS)
na.locf(dta, na.remaining = "keep")
```

The mutate_all is not necessary here, since na.locf is automatically applied to all columns (this is also the case when using na.locf of zoo)