# Define value by previous and actual row

Tags: r, data.table, locf

I have a `data.table` with two fields, `startvalue` and `endValue`, that I need to populate based in some information from the previous and actual rows. While this is somehow similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14689424/use-a-value-from-the-previous-row-in-an-r-data-table-calculation), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47206319/using-na-locf-to-carry-last-value-forward-ignoring-first-rows-when-first-observa), I haven't been able to get the results I want.

Dummy Data:

```
a <- data.table(user = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B"), 
                gap = c(1, 0, 2, 2, 3), 
                priority = c(1, 3, 2, 2, 1))
```

Then I fix the `startValue` for all priorities == 1:

```
setkey(a, user, priority)
a[priority == 1, startValue := 0]
```

and I set the `endValue` for those which `startValue` is already defined:

```
a[!is.na(startValue), endValue := startValue + gap*3]
```

Now comes the problem. I want the `startValue` in row 2 (user A, priority 2) to be the same as `endValue` of row 1, so I can calculate the new `endValue`. I **know** I can use a loop, but I wanted to know if it's possible to do it by using any other function or combination of functions.

I tried several combinations of `shift` and `zoo:na.locf` but always ended up messing the already existing values.

Expected result:

```
b <- structure(list(user = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B"), 
                    gap = c(1, 2, 0, 3, 2), 
                    priority = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2), 
                    startValue = c(0, 3, 9, 0, 9), 
                    endValue = c(3, 9, 9, 9, 15)), 
               row.names = c(NA, -5L), 
               class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I think here `a[priority == 1, startValue == 0]` you meant `a[priority == 1, startValue := 0]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `accumulate` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
library(data.table)
a[, endValue := accumulate(gap,  ~   .x + .y * 3, .init = 0)[-1], user
   ][, startValue := shift(endValue, fill = 0), user][]
all.equal(a, b, check.attributes = FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Or use `Reduce` from `base R` to create the 'endValue' column and then take the `lag` of the 'endValue' for creating the 'startValue' grouped by 'user'

```
a[, endValue := Reduce(function(x, y) x + y *3, gap, 
     accumulate = TRUE, init = 0)[-1], user]
```

Comment: it's so easy to despise `base R`, and yet it's so powerful!

Answer (score 1):

First, calculate end values using `cumsum`. Then use `shift` to get start values.

```
a[ , c("startValue", "endValue") := {
  e1 <- startValue[1] + gap[1] * 3
  endValue <- c(e1, e1 + cumsum(gap[-1] * 3))
  startValue <- shift(endValue, fill = startValue[1])
  .(startValue, endValue)
}, by = user]

#    user gap priority startValue endValue
# 1:    A   1        1          0        3
# 2:    A   2        2          3        9
# 3:    A   0        3          9        9
# 4:    B   3        1          0        9
# 5:    B   2        2          9       15
```